# Glue latest partition

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have set up a Glue crawler that creates a table on Athena using data from s3://mybucket/mytable/YYYY-MM-DD. There are many daily partitions under mytable, but i only need to use the latest daily partition. At the moment, the Glue crawler uses all the daily partitions causing duplicates on the Athena table. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the latest partition added in the table by applying filter https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.26.99/reference/services/glue/client/list_crawls.html